# Flink, Kafka and Zookeeper with an URI

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-flink

I am trying to connect to Kafka from my local machine:

```
kafkaParams.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", Defaults.BROKER_URL)
kafkaParams.setProperty("metadata.broker.list", Defaults.BROKER_URL)
kafkaParams.setProperty("group.id", "group_id")
kafkaParams.setProperty("auto.offset.reset", "earliest")
```

Perfectly fine, but my `BROKER_URI` is defined as follows `my-server.com:1234/my/subdirectory`.

I figured out that this phenomena is called a chroot path.

It throws the following error: `Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid url in bootstrap.servers: my-server.com:1234/my/subdirectory`

How do I solve this?

These are my dependencies:

```
val flinkVersion = "1.0.3"

"org.apache.flink" %% "flink-scala" % flinkVersion % "provided",
"org.apache.flink" %% "flink-streaming-scala" % flinkVersion % "provided",
"org.apache.flink" %% "flink-connector-kafka-0.9" % flinkVersion,
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try `host:port` format without the path context and slashes. If you have more than one servers it would be a list `host1:port1,host2:port2`

Reference: http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html

Comment: This gives the following error: `Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired while fetching topic metadata`

Comment: It is an indication the the format for the configuration is okay. Next thing to look for would be if there iptables or firewall running on the kafka instance. Can you telnet the kafka instance from your client box?

Comment: Fun thing is, I can connect using the Kafka console consumer: `./kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper my-server.com:1234/my/subdirectory --topic my-topic --from-beginning` works perfectly fine. And Telnet also works fine: `telnet my-server.com 1234`

Answer (score 0):

`bootstrap.servers` should be a comma-separated list like the following: `address1:port1,address2:port2,...,addressn:portn`. If you only have one Kafka broker you should input something like `localhost:9092` (unless you configured Kafka to run on another port).

You may refer on the [this post from dataArtisans](http://data-artisans.com/kafka-flink-a-practical-how-to/) for more details on how to make Flink and Kafka work together.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid. Zookeeper != Kafka. As you can see in the code, I used the same URL twice, but it turned out that they should be different.

I am trying to connect to Kafka from my local machine:

```
kafkaParams.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", Defaults.KAFKA_URL)
kafkaParams.setProperty("metadata.broker.list", Defaults.ZOOKEEPER_URL)
kafkaParams.setProperty("group.id", "group_id")
kafkaParams.setProperty("auto.offset.reset", "earliest")
```